# How do I disable warnings for a static framework in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, opencv, frameworks, warnings, clang

I'd like to build my Xcode project with `-Weverything`.  Unfortunately my project uses the opencv2.framework (built as a static framework for iOS), and the header files for that framework are not `-Weverything` clean.

When using clang from the command line, I can use the `-isystem` flag to specify system header files that should be ignored for compiler warnings.  Is there a similar feature for frameworks?  And if so, how do access it from Xcode?

Comment: Can you not add the `-isystem` flag to the `Other C Flags` or `Other Linker Flags` setting under Build Settings for your Project or Target?

Comment: I tried that.  `-isystem` doesn't work for frameworks because the include files aren't laid out the same way.  For example, when you include the file `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>`, the system actually expects to find that file in `opencv2.framework/Headers/opencv.hpp`

Answer (score 3):

As for me most of warnings occurred by documentation comments. So I go Project -> Build Settings and set Documentation Comments value to No. It hides all warnings also from static frameworks.